How to create smallest compressed backup of SQL Server databases intended for deletion?
I need to minimize SQL Server storage in preparation to migrate to cloud.
There are about 10 databases that are probably 99% junk/ needed for deletion. Maybe 100%. Reporting databases.
What's the best way to do some kind of compressed "backup" just for 6 months? ... It's about 500 GBs total ... would the LDF and MDF files be enough? (wouldn't save on storage but can put somewhere cheap).
It's something where it's mostly useless but occasionally some fringe case might be needed to bring it online. Not likely but possible.
I'm thinking there's probably a sufficient backup option. I don't need point in time or anything fancy. Just "here's the 10 dbs at this date (say today) in case of emergency". These are largely self contained reporting databases - not complicated applications. I understand corruption might be possible somehow, but willing to risk it.
This is an embarrassingly old version of SQL Server as well, 2014 if that is relevant.

Have you looked at Backup Compression, that should be much smaller than the MDF and LDF https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-compression-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Make a script to remove every data older than 6 months in every table. It's not easy way, but when you make it, you can use it after you backup databases every times, which saves the complete data and keeps the online data lightweight. Data partitioning can do the same thing, partitioning old data into another database and keeping only new data in the online production database. It's more complicated

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql

with compression --> BACKUP DATABASE [DummyDB] TO  DISK = N'C:\Backup\Backup.bak'  WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'DummyDB-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, compression ,NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 1 GO

Do you have a field in each table that reflects the time and date of this entry? If not, and you do not have a backup copy taken 6 months ago with which you can compare the current DB and select the delta - then it will be difficult to calculate the latest changes for 6 months.


You need to prepare the data you want to backup

You can't just take all the latest data for the last 6 months, SQL Server does not store the creation/modification date of each row.
So you need to select the records you want to backup at the logical level of the database. If you haven't specified the date column in advance, you can try to select the records you need by some other feature, for example, by ID - you can take the last 10,000 records.
Then create a new database and copy the data for each table there using
SELECT * INTO db_for_backup.table1
FROM sourcedb.table1
WHERE <6-month limitation condition>

This command will immediately create a table, but without indexes and foreign keys. This is good in your case, since their absence will reduce the size of the backup.

Create a compressed backup using the WITH COMPRESSION option

BACKUP DATABASE [db_for_backup] 
TO DISK = 'path-to-backup' 
WITH COMPRESSION

Alternatively, create a logical backup of the database. For example, by creating a Export Data Tier Application - this backup may take up even less space.

I didn't mean there was a data range of 6 months. ... I mean the entire backup (of the entire thing) ... only has to survive in cold storage for 6 months ... in other words, preferably something basic and without all the bells and whistles.

But the latter half seems like it'll work - thanks!
